# Rows of one table to be transferred as columns in another table

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure if this question has been asked already. I searched but dint get it .

I have an requirement where I have to select the list of columns based on where conditions .I have two tables .One table has list of values in one of the columns wrt unique IDs. This list of values will be COLUMNS in the second table. Ie in Table 1, tblsgnls the COLUMN clncgnls will have signals values.In Table 2 the values of clncgnls itself will be COLUMNS and these will hold some values. Now my requirement is that I need a select query which will display only those columns and its values for which I need (I will mention is the where clause).

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Is this Possible?

Also I need to select the required columns in Second table is S1 , S2 based on my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this should work for you, with the new explanation you have provided in the comments! :)

```
declare @cols nvarchar(100) = '', @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)

select @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(t.clncglns) + ',' from ( select distinct clncglns from table1 where sgnlid = 1) t

set @sqlQuery = 'select ' + left(@cols, LEN(@cols)-1) + ' from table2'
execute sp_executesql @sqlQuery
```

The @cols variable is holding the names of the columns you will need, comma separated. 
This (left(@cols, LEN(@cols)-1)) is done to remove the last comma on the string.

Comment: Hi Rigerta , I think there is confusion in understanding the requirement i guess. I have already have two tables as described . I need another view /table where i can select list of Columns ie S1 , S2 .....etc from Table 1 dynamically and pass this list of column to get the data from the table 2.Also I have edited the Table 1 figure as well. This will clear confusion. Now my requirement, For example , I have unique ID ie SGNLID=2 then i NEED ONLY S2 AND S3,

Comment: AND USING THIS I HAVE TO DYNAMICALLY PASS THIS VALUE TO SELECT THE S2 AND S3 FROM TABLE 2 IE., I NEED SELECT QUERY SOMETHING LIKE THIS          :    "SELECT S2,S3 FROM <TABLE 2>".   So i need some query which can set the columns dynamically based on unique ID , hence if SGNLID=1  i need only columns in table 2 are S1 and S2 and if its SGNLID=4 the I need all 4 ie S1,S2,S3 ,S4.